# Boost Geometry doesn't copy the attributes of my custom point class

Tags: c++, boost-geometry

I am attempting to use Boost Geometry with a custom vertex class that has x, y and many parameters for rendering such as texture coordinates.  I registered the custom class using
[`BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/adapted/register/boost_geometry_register_point_2d.html)
and the algorithms such as [`union_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/union_.html) work but only x,y are valid.  (I am a C++ veteran but have never learned generic programming.)
I can demonstrate the problem when I take an instance of my vertex and use 
`boost::geometry::append( boostPolygon, myVertex );`

I can trace the append call in the debugger and I see that a default constructed instance of my vertex is being created and then the accessors of my vertex class are being called to copy the x, and y values leaving all the rest of the parameters as set in the default constructor.

What I really want is for [`boost::geometry::append()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/append.html) to behave exactly like `boostPolygon.outer().push_back( myVertex);`
So I replaced the `append` call with the above `push_back` and it added the points to the polygon as I wanted but then when I called `union_()` on the polygons they lost all the members other than x and y again.

I figure that what I want is a typical use-case so it is best to ask rather than guess how to handle this.  I've seen the examples of how to adapt a class but my template kung-fu isn't enough to follow along.  So do I need to add more adaption or is there something simple I need to do?

Comment: I should add that I am using boost 1.47 and due to rules beyond my control I cannot upgrade.